# Php function hex or rgb color to color name

Tags: php, function

Is there a php function that return the closest colorname by give the rgb or hex color as parameter? I have seared a lot but can't find a function that does that job.

Please help

Comment: When you say "closest" - how close do you mean?  Considering standard RGB with R, G, and B all being between 0x00 and 0xFF, you'll get over 16.5 million colours.  Majority of them won't even have a proper name assigned to them.

Comment: This may not be the best way to go because you will have several different colors with the same name. Why not just show the color instead of list its name?

Answer (score 2):

See my Code below. I use it to copy Logo Color to change the site theme automatically at run-time. Hope it works!

Simply pass the image URL as parameter in the function.

```
function CopyLogoColor($logo_path){
    $i = imagecreatefromjpeg($logo_path);

    $rTotal = 0;
    $gTotal =0;
    $bTotal = 0;
    $total = 0;

    for ( $x=0 ; $x<imagesx($i) ; $x++){
        for ( $y=0 ; $y<imagesy($i) ; $y++ ) {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($i,$x,$y);
            $r   = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g   = ($rgb >> 8)& 0xFF;
            $b   = $rgb & 0xFF;

            $rTotal += $r;
            $gTotal += $g;
            $bTotal += $b;
            $total++;

        }
    }

    $rAverage = round($rTotal/$total);
    $gAverage = round($gTotal/$total);
    $bAverage = round($bTotal/$total);



    $r = intval($rAverage); 
    $g = intval($gAverage);
    $b = intval($bAverage);

    $r = dechex($r<0?0:($r>255?255:$r));
    $g = dechex($g<0?0:($g>255?255:$g));
    $b = dechex($b<0?0:($b>255?255:$b));

    $color = (strlen($r) < 2?'0':'').$r;
    $color .= (strlen($g) < 2?'0':'').$g;
    $color .= (strlen($b) < 2?'0':'').$b;

    return '#'.$color;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no such function,

you will need to write your own function that fetches the R, G and B value induvidualy,
and loops them to each value and find out wat the closest is ( total of R and G and B ofset the smallest)

you can find all HTML colornames here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#ColorKeywords

---

**ex:**

user gives in [250,1,2] (olwost red). you have a array:

```
$input = [255,1,2]
$colors = array("red" => [255,0,0],"green"=>[0,255,0]) // used JS array to be quiker

foreach( $ .. as .. $color){ // or a sort function?
// get diff, key 0 is red key 2 is blue
$diff = abs($input[0] - $color[0]) + ... + abs($input[2] - $color[2]); 
}
```

red will have a diff of: 5 + 1 + 2 
green will have: 250 + 254 + 2 
blue is : 250 + 1 + 253

red has the lowest sum, so it must be colsest to red.
blue is the next, and then comes green

Comment: Sorry i stil didn't get it:
Now i have this:

$arr_input = array(255,1,2]);

$arr_colors = array(
 'red'  => 255,0,0,
 'green' => 0,255,0
);

function returnColorNameByRgbcolor($rgb_color);
 foreach($arr_colors as $color) {
  // get diff, key 0 is red key 2 is blue
  echo $arr_input[0];
  
  // echo $arr_input[0] - $color[0]   . '--' . $arr_input[1] - $color[1]  . '--' . $arr_input[2] - $color[2];
  $diff = abs($arr_input[0] - $color[0]) + abs($arr_input[1] - $color[1]) + abs($arr_input[2] - $color[2]); 
  echo $diff . '<br />';
  // echo $diff . '<br />';
  
 }
 
 return $color_name;
}

Comment: you need to compare the diff's, append their vanue to the collors array, and then sort on that array on that key.

Comment: Thanks to gar-onn

This is de result

$arr_input = array(250,1,2);

$arr_colors = array(
 'red'  => array(255,0,0),
 'green' => array(0,255,0)
);

foreach($arr_colors as $key=>$color) {
 $diff = abs($arr_input[0] - $color[0]) + abs($arr_input[1] - $color[1]) + abs($arr_input[2] - $color[2]);
 $array[$key] = $diff;
}
print_r($array);